# Mask in a function that converts decimals number into any system

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a function that converts num to any system from decimal.

```
def getMask():
    mask =""
    for i in range(48,58):
        mask += chr(i)
    for i in range(65,91):
        mask += chr(i)
    return mask

mask = getMask()
print(mask)

def decToAny(val, system):
    temp = ""
    while val >0:
        temp += mask[val%system]
        val //= system
    return reverseVal(temp)

print(decToAny(10,2))
```

But i dont really understand what is and why i need this **mask**. I can accept this fact but i dont fully understand it. Can you explain to me as simple as possible, what is and why i need this mask?

Comment: `mask` is just a string, indexed by a digit value, that contains the character for the digit.  So `mask[0]` is `'0'`, `mask[9]` is `'9'`, `mask[10]` is `'A'`, etc.  Why don't you try *looking* at it?  Just `print(mask)`.  It should be pretty obvious.  It looks like this:  `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

Comment: Mask contains the representation of a digit, that's numbers and then letters for bases higher than 10 (eg: hexadecimal). By taking the modulo you know the index for that specific digit. Then divide by the base to get the next digit

Comment: *"into any system"*: well, technically, not *any* system. It wouldn't work with `system` greater than 36.

Answer (score 4):

### Don't call this variable "mask"

I don't blame you for being confused about this `mask` variable.

The choice of variable name `mask` is counterintuitive and looks like an attempt to obfuscate the code.

This variable should be called simply `symbols` or `alphabet` or something similar; "symbols" and "alphabet" are self-explanatory and mean what they mean.

The name `mask` evokes a mask that should be applied to an array, like a bitmask, an affinity mask or an image mask; this concept is completely unrelated to this code and choosing a variable name unrelated to the variable's meaning just makes everything harder to understand for no reason.

Also, relying on knowledge of ascii values 48, 58, 65, 91 just makes everything obscure for no good reason. Using numbers with unexplained precise values like this in code should be avoided unless you have a very good reason to use them. The concept is sometimes referred to as [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) as it looks like part of the algorithm's logic is hidden behind a carefully-choosen obscure number with no obvious meaning, but an important hidden meaning with magical powers.

You could get rid of function `getMask` entirely; and replace it with:

```py
import string
symbols = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase
```

Or even more explicit:

```
symbols = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

### Don't say "decimal" if your code doesn't use decimal

Numbers are not stored in decimal in computers. When you have a variable representing an integer in python, internally it is stored in binary, not in decimal; and as a programmer you should simply treat it like a "number", not a "decimal representation of a number" (which it is not) nor a "binary representation of a number" (which it is internally, but still you should treat it as a number).

So your function should probably be called `numberToString` or `writeNumberInAnyBase` or something similar, but not `decToAny` since there is no decimal at all. In fact if you need to print a number of decimal, you can use your function and specify a base of 10.

### Handle the special case of 0, and negative numbers

Your code returns an empty string `""` if you call it with `val=0`. From a logical point of view, this is very satisfying, but in general we prefer to represent zero by the explicit string `"0"` rather than by the empty string `""`.

Finally your code should probably check if the number is negative, and if it is, add `"-"` in front of the result.

### Beware of [Shlemiel the painter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)

In python, it is easy to add an element to a list: type `list` has `.append( )` to add one element to a list. However, it is not easy to add one element to a string. Type `str` has no `append` method.

When you write `temp = temp + c` to add some character `c` at the end of `temp`, what happens behind the scene is that a new string is created, in which the content of `temp` and `c` are copied. This is relatively slow if the string is long.

Since you do this in a loop, all the digits are copied many times. This is inefficient. Instead you can add the digits to a list with `.append`, and once you have all the digits, join all the digits at once into a string using `''.join(...)`. This will be more efficient.

### Final code

```py
import string

def numberToBase(num, base):
    alphabet = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase
    # or equivalently alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    assert(base <= len(alphabet))
    if num == 0:
        return "0"
    if num < 0:
        sign, num = "-", -num
    else:
        sign = ""
    rev = []
    while num > 0:
        num, unit_digit = divmod(num, base)
        rev.append(alphabet[unit_digit])
    return sign + "".join(reversed(rev))

# tests

def test_numberToBase():
    numbers = [-17, -1, 0, 3, 8, 10, 357]
    bases = [2, 10, 16, 36]
    for n in numbers:
        print(f'[{n:3}]10  --> ', end='')
        print('\n             '.join(f'[{numberToBase(n, b):>9}]{b}' for b in bases))

test_numberToBase()
```

### Allow user to supply their own alphabet

The alphabet `'0123456789'` works well for any base up to 10. The extended alphabet `'0123456789ABCDEF'` is standard for base-16, which is fairly common. It's natural to extend this to `'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'` for bases up to 36.

But perhaps the user wants to use their own alphabet? This way they can handle bases larger than 36, or use symbols other than `ABCD...` if they prefer.

```py
def numberToBase(num, base=None, alphabet=None):
    if base is None and alphabet is None:
        base = 10
        alphabet = '0123456789'
    elif base is None:
        base = len(alphabet)
    elif alphabet is None:
        alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    assert(base <= len(alphabet))
    if num == 0:
        return "0"
    if num < 0:
        sign, num = "-", -num
    else:
        sign = ""
    rev = []
    while num > 0:
        num, unit_digit = divmod(num, base)
        rev.append(alphabet[unit_digit])
    return sign + "".join(reversed(rev))

# tests
# ...
print(numberToBase(2545, alphabet='0123456789XJQK') # ten jack queen king
# 'QKJ'

print(numberToBase(2545, alphabet='ZERO ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE'.split()))
# TWOFIVEFOURFIVE
```

Comment: In cases of not-so-obvious constants (`string.printable` is widely used, but still), it's better to use fully-qualified names unless you refer to this variable many times. `alphabet = string.printable[:10+26].upper()` would be more understandable without having to review imports first (assuming that standard module names are much more well-known than their specific members). Or perhaps `string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase` instead of indexing: this does not assume that you know order of `string.printable`, but only that `string.digits` and `string.ascii_uppercase` are reasonably sorted.

Comment: string += has been optimized: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079181/how-is-the-s-sc-string-concat-optimization-decided

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Yes I am aware. I decided not to mention that. Note the "Should python programmers rely on this?" paragraph in the answer to the question you linked.